# Powershell script to remove (i.e. deny) NTFS permissions for a Domain\User

Tags: powershell

I am wanting to deploy a powershell script to remove NTFS permissions from a domain\user for a UNC path.

This is not a new task and in fact there are plenty of examples when you search on Google.

Unfortunately, I have tried a number of them, and while they execute without error, they're not updating the NTFS permissions on the selected user.

Here is my latest attempt (based on examples that I have tried), which also does not error, but doesn't change the NTFS permissions.

`
$acl = Get-Acl \Server\Share$\Path
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Domain\Username","FullControl","Deny")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl \Server\Share$\Path

$acl = Get-Acl \Server\Share$\Path
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Domain\Username","Write","Deny")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl \Server\Share$\Path

$acl = Get-Acl \Server\Share$\Path
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Domain\Username","Modify","Deny")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl \Server\Share$\Path

$acl = Get-Acl \Server\Share$\Path
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Domain\Username","Read","Deny")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl \Server\Share$\Path
`
If this code looks "good", after troubleshooting suggestions, so that I can identify why it isn't working.

Alternatively, if the code is flawed, after a working example.

Comment: Did you mean to post the same code block 4 times, or am I missing a subtle difference between them all? Also your path “\Server\Share$\Path” looks suspiciously like you’re trying to set permissions on a remote share (although a UNC starts with two “\”) - I don’t *think* you can do that. If you are, you’ll need to start a PS remoting session onto the server and do it “locally”.

Comment: Hello,

It's a similar code block, each code block attempts to remove a different permission (e.g. Full Control, Modify etc.)

I am trying to access a remote share. For some reason, I have noticed that the code that I pasted has had one of the leading slashes removed from the UNC path.

The PS remoting session that you refer to is probably the issue why this code has not been working for me.

I will look into this. Thank you.

Comment: The leading slashes are *removed* from your code because you did not format your code as code!! How to [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly on SO.  

Comment: If you want to *remove* a permission of a user from a file system object shouldn't you use `$acl.RemoveAccessRule($AccessRule)` instead of `$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)`?  ‍♂️

Comment: Hello Olaf,
In the example I was trying to add a deny entry which would override the allow, but I take your point, that another approach (and probably cleaner) would be to Remove the allow entry.

Comment: No, it would not. A deny would be added additionally to the ACL.  